# Setting minZoom at runtime in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to set `maxZoom` and `minZoom` at runtime.

Initially I set `maxZoom` and `minZoom` as shown in below code

```
new this.Map("map1", {
    basemap: "streets",
    center: new this.Point3(-98.35, 39.50),
    zoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 5
});
```

After some time user want to change the Min and Max zoom levels at runtime.
So I tried as below code, but not workout.

```
this.selMapObj.setView(new this.MapView({
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 9,
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use `constraint` object property of the `MapView`, that is were `minZoom` and `maxZoom` are set.

Here is an example I made for you,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Zoom Constraints</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>
    <script>
      require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView"], function(Map, MapView) {
        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets"
        });
        var view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 4,
          center: [15, 65]
        });
        document.getElementById("min").value = view.constraints.minZoom;
        document.getElementById("max").value = view.constraints.maxZoom;
        document.getElementById("updateButton").onclick = function updateZoomConstraints() {
          var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
          var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
          console.log(`min:${min} max:${max}`)
          if (min < max) {
            view.constraints.minZoom = min;
            view.constraints.maxZoom = max;
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="min">Min Zoom:</label>
      <input id="min" type="number" min="2" max="18">
      <label for="max">Max Zoom:</label>
      <input id="max" type="number" min="0" max="17">
      <button id="updateButton">Update Zoom Constraints</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[ArcGIS API - MapView consraints](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#constraints)